# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fatal-error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp\www\moneymanager18_8_15\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 221
```

This happens during uploading.file is getting uploaded,but the same time this error shows.

Comment: Looks like your MySQL Server is under too much load. Try optimizing it. `:)`

Comment: how to optimize mysql server

Answer (score 13):

Write this above your controller.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```

Comment: This is going to be a hackjob than fixing the right thing, what exactly happens. For eg., if there's an infinite loop going on, even this would fail. Agree?

Comment: <?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
class Money_c extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));

Comment: Enable profiler and see which query is taking time.

Comment: Write $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); anywhere within your Controller functions.[Read](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87349/discussion-between-bugfixer-and-manjusha).

Comment: Using it under specific controller worked for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

There is a something that CodeIgniter not include this in their documentation.
Go to the page in `system/core/CodeIgniter.php` and search this and change it according to your requirement

```
if (function_exists("set_time_limit") == TRUE AND @ini_get("safe_mode") == 0)
{
    @set_time_limit(300);// change according to your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this error you need to set execution time to unlimited or need to increase it.

you need to open root index.php file in root folder and set execution time.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // 0 = Unlimited
```