# Codeigniter cannot display more than 20 records from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, wampserver

While retrieving data from MySQL database, `codeigniter` cannot retrieve more than 20 records.

The table has nearly 600 records.

**Model**

```
function get_demo(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('demo_tbl');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Page not showing anything (even not showing any error).

[image: not_showing_any_data]

But if I give `limit`...

```
function get_demo(){
    //$this->db->cache_on();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('demo_tbl');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit(20);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Page showing records...

[image: showing_data]

**It is a strange behavior.**

I cannot understand where is the error.
What should I do to display all records ?

I am using `wampserver 2.2`.

Comment: "_Page not showing anything (even not showing any error)_" Anything in the error log?

Comment: Did you try limit over 20?

Comment: may be `max_execution_time` issue here!!

Comment: Looks like a timeout issue to me. Try increasing the timeout value on the site.

Comment: @AnkitSingh yes I tried. but showing no data.

Comment: Me too @Saty, or memory_limit

Comment: @WEI_DBA how to increase ?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not familiar with `wampserver 2.2`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php or http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: can do that at code level using ini_set or can modify in php.ini file
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32088809/4662759

Comment: Tried everything....but failed.

Comment: When you make changes in php.ini or any other wampserver changes, don't forget to restart. Make sure you have restarted the server

Comment: I am using Code Igniter for years and I used it with a lot more than 20 records! This seems to be a configuration problem in the Wampserver 2.2 and especially in MySQL. Here is a similar problem discussed:
https://serverfault.com/questions/74313/what-could-cause-an-101-error-in-wamp-under-windows-7 Check which MySQL DLL you use in WAMP.

Comment: I always restart wampserver.

Comment: What version of CI are you using?  You can also clean up your function by just doing: `return $this->db->select('*')->order_by('id', 'desc')->get('demo_tbl')->result()`; Also is your table indexed

Comment: enable the log and tell us what it says. @Raj